# linq To XML update values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi looking for better solution than my -
my xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ITEM>
  <FIELD name="A" value="3" />
  <FIELD name="B" value="testname" />
  <FIELD name="C" value="test" />
  <FIELD name="D" value="desctest%" />
  <FIELD name="E" value="A@" />
  <FIELD name="F" value="value^" />
  <FIELD name="G" value="testvalue%" />
  <FIELD name="H" value="^0" />
</ITEM>
```

here is code to replace all special character -

```
   string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\DilipLearn\xml_char\xml_char\test.txt");

                char[] specialchar = { '~', '`', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', };
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
                var elements = doc.Elements().Descendants()
                 .Where(arg => arg.Attribute("value").Value.IndexOfAny(specialchar) >= 0)// == arg.Attribute("value").Value)
                 ;


                foreach (var element in elements)
                {

                    element.SetAttributeValue("value", Regex.Replace(element.Attribute("value").Value, @"[@$%!@#^&*()]", match =>
                     {
                         switch (match.Value)
                         {
                             case "^": return "&#94;";
                             case "@": return "&#64;";
                             case "%": return "&#37;";
                             case "$": return "&#36;";
                             case "&": return "&#38;";
                             default: return "";
                         }
                     })
                                             );
                }


                string resultstring = string.Concat(doc.Declaration.ToString(), doc.ToString());
```

everything its working fine .

I just want to know there is any better way to do this ? for example without looping or some other improvement .

Thanks .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow (you can get feedback for working code there, SO is for not-working code).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer There is no rule that says that SO is for not-working code. Rather, the problem with this question is that [there is no specific programming problem to be solved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313266/1157100).

Comment: whats wrong if i asking better suggestion ? there is 1000 way to solve any problem i know one way , asking for some different opinion which help me to optimize my process .

Comment: as long as i m posting question related to programming should not be any issue .

Comment: If you are seeking improvements in general, then the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since there is no specific programming problem to be solved. However, asking for suggestions to improve your code is exactly what Code Review is for. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try, instead of `foreach` loop:

```
elements.ToList().ForEach(element =>
        {
            var newValue = Regex.Replace(element.Attribute("value").Value, @"[@$%!@#^&*()]", match => "&#" + ((int)match.Value[0]).ToString()) + ";";
            element.SetAttributeValue("value", newValue);
        });
```

I'm converting elements to `List<XElement>` so I can use ForEach (extension method from `System.Linq` namespace). In the loop, I am casting matched character to it's `int` representation, thus getting it's ASCII value. And (a bit dirty :)) adding `&#` and `;`.

Normally, I would try to use `WebUtility.HtmlEncode`, but because chars such as @ are unicode, encoded string would be same as non-encoded.

Alternatively, you can try using `Dictionary<char, string>` as mapping table (key is "problematic" char (such as `@`, `#`, `$` etc), and key is replacement value (ie `"&#64;"`). That way you would skip `switch case`.